# Centre Decimal aligned multicolumn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have some decimal values in a table that I have aligned by decimal point but I would like them to be centred to the column. So far I have:

```
\begin{tabular}{l r@{}l r@{}l r@{}l r@{}l}
\toprule
Weeks & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Best Total} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Best Start} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Best End} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Loops}\\
\midrule
26 & 99&.72 & 17&& 20&& 6,&201\\
52 & 99&.72 & 17&& 20&& 48,&230\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `siunitx`; the value you give to `table-format` is in the form “number of digits in the integral part”, a period and “number of decimal digits”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits]
}
\toprule
Weeks & {Best Total} & {Best Start} & {Best End} & {Loops}\\
\midrule
26 & 99.72 & 17& 20&  6201\\
52 & 99.72 & 17& 20& 48230\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the comma separator for thousands. If you really want it, add

```
\sisetup{group-separator={,}}
```

before `\begin{document}` and the same input as before will produce

[image]

Comment: Marked as best answer for a recommending a package that requires the least modification of data in the file. Plus it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ D..{-1} D..{-1} D..{-1} D..{-1} D,,{-1}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Weeks} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Best Total} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Best Start} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Best End} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Loops}\\
\midrule
26 & 99.72 & 17& 20& 6,201\\
52 & 99.72 & 17& 20& 48,230\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```